# How to Set Variables and Process Variable for MySQL in a Perl Script

Tags: mysql, perl, variables

HERE IS MY TABLE EXAMPLE:

```
Id  |   Time     |  Predicted |   Actual |   High
----+------------+------------+----------+---------
1   |   01:00:00 |  100       |    100   |    NULL
2   |   02:00:00 |  200       |    50    |    NULL
3   |   03:00:00 |  150       |    100   |    NULL
4   |   04:00:00 |  180       |    80    |    NULL
```

I want to find highest value in Predicted and place it in the 'High' column (IN A SPECIFIC ROW)

========= USING THE FOLLOWING SYNTAX I AM ABLE TO ACHIEVE THIS MANUALLY IN SQL WITH THE FOLLOWING:

SET @peak=(SELECT MAX(Predicted) FROM table);

UPDATE table SET Peak=@peak WHERE Id='1';

```
Id  |  Time      |  Predicted |    Actual |   High
----+------------+------------+-----------+---------
1   |   01:00:00 |  100       |    100    |   200
2   |   02:00:00 |  200       |    50     |   NULL
3   |   03:00:00 |  150       |    100    |   NULL
4   |   04:00:00 |  180       |    80     |   NULL

=======================================
```

However, when I attempt to use the above syntax in a Perl script it fails due to the '@" or any variable symbol.  Here is the Perl syntax I attempted to overcome the variable issue with no real favourable results. This is true even when placing the @peak variable in the 'execute(@peak) with ? in the pre-leading syntax' parameter:

```
my $Id_var= '1';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( 'set @peak  = (SELECT MAX(Predicted) FROM table)' );
my $sti = $dbh->prepare ( "UPDATE table SET Peak = @peak  WHERE Id = ? " );
$sth->execute;
$sth->finish();
$sti->execute('$Id_var');
$sti->finish();
$dbh->commit or die $DBI::errstr;
```

With the following error:
*Global symbol "@peak" requires explicit package name*

**I would appreciate any help to get this working within my Perl script.**

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `finish` after your `execute` statements. Just about the only time you need to call `finish` is if you only want to fetch a subset of the results returned by a `SELECT`. See the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#finish) for details.

Comment: More importantly, the variable `$Id_var` is in single quotes, so its value won't be interpolated. That means your query will only update rows where `Id` is the literal string `$Id_var`, which I doubt is what you want. You can leave off the quotes (you've used a placeholder, so it will quote the value automatically if necessary): `$sti->execute($Id_var);`

Comment: Why did you switch from single quotes on the select statement to double quotes on the update statement? If you have stuck with single quotes then it would have just worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl sees @peak as an array. Try referring to it as \@peak. The back slash means interpret next character literally.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the @ symbal (which denotes an array variable) or use single quotes, eg

```
my $sti = $dbh->prepare ( "UPDATE table SET Peak = \@peak WHE...
```

Or, use a single quote

```
my $sti = $dbh->prepare ( 'UPDATE table SET Peak = @peak WHE...
```